# Problem to crop edges when creating pdf using standalone package

Tags: pdf, standalone

I am trying to make a pdf figure comprised of several other figures arranged in a table manner. 
I am using the standalone documentclass. However the results I get are far from optimal. 
I am using Texstudio for Windows, PDFLatex command on Miktek 2.9:
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

When using the first two options for the standalone package (in the MWE) I obtain a pdf where the upper and lower sides are cropped but not on left and right sides. 
When using the varwidth option to true, I obtain the desired cropped edges but the caption titles ((a),(b),...) are all left justified and brackets are gone.
Whenever I remove the preview=true option I am filled with errors.

I attach the MWE; in the original, figure (d) is twice as tall as this black box.

```
%\documentclass[border=2pt,crop=true,preview=true]{standalone} % works but spaces on sides
%\documentclass[border=2pt,preview=true]{standalone} % works but spaces on sides
%\documentclass[varwidth=true,preview=true]{standalone} % works reduces side spaces, but captions ragged left without brackets
\documentclass[varwidth=true]{standalone} % same

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{X X} % @{}
        \begin{tabular}{c} 
            \begin{subfigure}[]{0.99\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
            \caption{}
            \label{a}
            \end{subfigure} \\ 
            \begin{subfigure}[]{0.99\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
            \caption{}
            \label{b}
            \end{subfigure} \\ 
            \begin{subfigure}[]{0.99\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{}
            \caption{}
            \label{c}
            \end{subfigure}
        \end{tabular}
        & 
        \begin{tabular}{c} 
            \begin{subfigure}[]{0.99\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]{}
            \caption{}
            \label{d}
            \end{subfigure}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate your comments on what is going on here and what can be done to solve this problem.

[image: PDF created without varwidth]

[image: PDF created with varwidth option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have used `@{}` at appropriate places. Then the `subfigure` and `figure` environments are removed. Then it is time to load `caption` package and use its `\captionof` macro. This macro is enclosed within a `\parbox` (a need).

Additionally the subcaption is loaded like

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

So the full code will be

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.75\textwidth}{@{}X X@{}} % @{}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c}
            \parbox{\linewidth}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{a}
            }
            \\
            \parbox{\linewidth}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{b}
            }
            \\
            \parbox{\linewidth}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{c}
            }
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c}
            \parbox{\linewidth}{%
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
            \captionof{subfigure}{}
            \label{d}
            }
        \end{tabular}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Harish, worked as intended and responded in less than or about an hour after posting this. Do you know why the figure environment was not adequate for the standalone to work?, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @RobertoST `figure` is a float and `standalone` is meant for producing standalone files. Hence don't use `figure` with `standalone`.